# Grails controller sending weird JSON back to browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, grails-controller

I have a Grails (2.3.6) app serving an HTML form with two `<select/>` elements in it: one that allows users to select a `country` and then, subsequently, a `state`. When the user selects a new `country`, I want to update the `state` select element. To do this, on country `change()`, I need to ask the server for the new list of state options to populate the state `<select/>` with:

```
<div class="blah">
    <label for="state">State</label><br/>
    <g:select id="state" name="state" from="${states}" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#country').change(function() {
        var countryName = $('#country option:selected').val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "getStateListByCountry",
            type:"get",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                countryName: countryName
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Received following from server: " + data);

                $("#state option").remove();

                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('#state')
                        .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value",key)
                        .text(value));
                });
            },
            error: function(xhr){
                alert(xhr.responseText); //<----TODO: Replace
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And then, on the Grails/server side:

```
class MyController {
    // Stub this with dummy data to return.
    def getStateListByCountry() {
        List<String> states = new ArrayList<String>()
        states.add("NY")
        states.add("NH")
        states.add("VT")

        println "Sending the following back to browser: ${states}."

        states
    }       
}
```

At runtime, when I select a new country in the '`#country`' select, I see the following message in the Grails app log:

> Sending the following back to browser: [NY, NH, VT].

But then in the browser I get an `alert(...)` that prints **the HTML of my custom "Page Not Found" error page!**

Furthermore my '`#state`' select doesn't update with the 3 dummy state values. So the Grails server is correctly receiving the client request, and trying to send back my dummy state list, but somewhere along the way a "Page Not Found" template is getting returned. Any ideas as to what is going on here **or what is wrong with my code?**

---

#### Update

It seems that my `error` function is executing, and the bizarre HTML I've been seeing inside the `alert` is actually the `xhr.responseText` passed into that method.

The Grails server isn't reporting any errors in the logs, and a `println` in the `getStateListByCountry` method confirms that the JSON being returned to the client is `["NY","VT","NH"]`. So it seems that the server is returning an error somehow, and jQuery is executing the `error` handler, **not** the `success` handler...ideas?

Comment: You can update "states" using grails template I think this will be much easier than handling all things via javascript.

Comment: Thanks @Abdullah (+1) - I'm not familiar with this "template" concept - would you mind sharing a link or jsFiddle/gist for how this might work? Thanks again!

Comment: To send JSON use `states as JSON`

Comment: Everything is fine in your code, just need to send response from controller like: `render states as grails.converters.JSON`

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's an SSCCE, shows research, shows effort, and isn't a dupe.

Comment: that is not JSON, is the states.toString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on the client-side. I had specified a `dataType` of "json" but was not returning JSON via the Grails `render(...)` method.

Comment: I added some things to my answer, please check it out.

Comment: Regarding the bounty: It doesn't work like you expected. Have a look at [How bounty is awarded](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) (You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.) :)

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro but my intention was never to award myself the bounty. That's like giving yourself a zero-interest loan; why do it?

Answer (score 4):

Try to add a: "as JSON" in states:

```
states as JSON
```

EDIT:

smeeb, I made a test environment here and changed your:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "controllername/getStateListByCountry",
    type: "get",
    data: countryName,
```

to use the controllername before the actio, no need for dataType, and the return to:

```
render states as JSON
```

and It worked, can you try it?

Comment: Thanks @Vitor Hugo (+1) - however this doesn't fix my issue; same exact problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: Also, please see my update, the `error` handler is executing, which is why I'm seeing bizarre response text from the server...

Answer (score 2):

Call a function on change of country

```
   jQuery('#country').change(function() {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "getStateListByCountry",
        type:"get",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            countryName: countryName
        },
       success: function(data) {
        $('#divId').replaceWith(data);

    }
```

and on the specified url **getStateListByCountry** retrieve **states**
and render a template from there

```
render template: 'nameOfTemplate', model: [states:States.list()]
```

and then replace the div with new template in you success call back.

In the template you should put g:select box and populate that select box with states list passed in model.
You can create template as you are creating view only you have to put an underscore **"_"** before the name of template. More about [Templates and Views](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#viewsAndTemplates)

Comment: Thanks @Abdullah (+1) - although this is an interesting solution I'm not interested in it for this particular problem. Please see my update; it looks like the `error` handler is executing, which is why I'm seeing the bizarre response text. Any ideas? Thanks again!